# Relational database model customer, orders and orderpositions

Tags: model, h2, relational

I am stuck in creating the correct relational model for my h2 database.

The structure is like following:

- One customer owns many orders
- One order owns many order positions
- One order positions owns many under order positions

Do I create for each customer one order table and for each position one table with under order positions?

Or what would be the correct model?

After google 2 hours I didn't find what I am looking for.

Do you have maybe a link to such a tutorial?

EDIT:
Thank you for your fast answer! I have one order where the customer ordered 4 products. Each product consists out of manufactures. For example: 
Productname: MixSalad
This product consists out of 
manufacture 1, 2 and 3.
manufacture 1 consists out of the components 1 and 2.

MixSalad

-Manufacture 1
 |-Component 1
 |-Component 2
-Manufacture 2
|-Component 3
|-Component 4
-Manufacture 3
|-Component 1
|-Component 3

Comment: What do you mean by order position?

Comment: may be [this link](http://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/) help to you

Comment: What exactly were you googling for.. Tutorials on creating tables with PK/FK relationships? Could you share the PK/FK attributes of these tables.. That would help users creating the schema.

Comment: The order position is the e.g. the Component 1